# aws-sdk with fips compliance upload

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-js, fips, aws-sdk-nodejs

Doing a normal putObject request that used to work on a regular amazon ec2 deployment now no longer works when running on an ec2 instance in gov cloud. The error response is

```
 error:060A80A3:digital envelope routines:FIPS_DIGESTINIT:disabled for fips
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this issue?

I opened a ticket with aws-sdk-js - I think it is because their library uses some internal crypto instead of the fips enabled crypto on the ec2 instance.

Download works fine (probably because there is no md5 hash being created?). putObject is the only problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

AWS GovCloud uses FIPS 140-2 validated cryptographic modules to support compliance with FIPS 140-2 in all HTTPS endpoints unless otherwise noted.

Amazon S3 in GovCloud provides both FIPS and Non-FIPS endpoints

- FIPS: s3-fips.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com, s3.dualstack.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
- Non-FIPS: s3.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com

I‘m not familiar with the implementation specifics of the SDK you’re using, but using the non-FIPS endpoint might solve the issue (in case FIPS isn’t a requirement for the data you want to store).

You can find more info about the various service endpoints [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/using-govcloud-endpoints.html) and about the differences in S3 on GovCloud [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-s3.html).

Comment: thanks. no i tried using regular non-fips non-gov regions like 'us-east-1' and that will still give the error mentioned about. searched https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk for endpoints... normally you just set bucket, key, body and region. I did try seting endpoint directly according to this example, here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2653 but still get the same error